# Minimizing function by changing parameters using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimization

I want to minimize the next equation by changing the parameters B0, B1, B2, B3, T1, T2. The variable y just another variable to calculate the objective function.
I just need help to minimize that function (used as an objective function) by changing the parameters but I can't get the results. I tried with scipy but I did not change the parameters.
By running the function, I get the result that I want:

```
funcion_opt(B0, B1, B2, B3, T1, T2)
output:  64.30571361326217
```

But when I do the minimization, I get the next result:

```
res = optimize.minimize(funcion_opt, parameters, args=(beta0, beta1, beta2, 
beta3, tau1, tau2))
output: funcion_opt() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I know that the mistake is the way to introduce the parameters and there is where I need help. Sorry if it's not clear enough.

Small example of my issue:

```
y = np.array([98.494500, 97.828500, 97.610000, 97.314000, 97.014500, 
92.959000, 96.696222])
def objective(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2):
    return (y * b0 + b1) - ( y * b2 + b3) + t1 + t2
    x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of b0, b1...
    result = minimize(objective, x0, args=(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2))
```

I know that the inputs in the function are wrong, the variables that are constant is y, and I want to change the values of the parameters b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2. So the minimize function I need is the one that takes the return of the function and by tuning the parameters, minimizes the error. So maybe the mistake is when setting the objective function.

This is a dummy function, the original one is the sum of square errors.
After that I need to minimize tat function by changing the values of the parameters inside the return b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2 because in the function these parameters are set as. Discount factor is irrelevant I just need how to change the parameters to the ones that minimize the objective function:

When I try to minimize get the output that the error is the same and the parameters did not change.
Any assistance with this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you tried, even if it didn't work. Minimization in scipy is pretty straightforward, I'm sure it will be some minor bug. But if you don't post the code with which you have problems, nobody can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry I am new in this, I will edit the code. Thank you so much

Comment: It's ok, no need to apologize. But it's still not the whole code - when you're asking here it's best that you create "minimal working example" (in this case, "working" means "producing the same bug"), which someone can copy and try and figure out what's wrong. Btw, this way (creating minimal working example), you usually figure out what's wrong by yourself (did it myself many times). See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Another thing, which you should clarify is what exactly `y` parameter is, and if it's ok to optimize using constant 'y' parameter. Because base of your problem is, that you're using `args` to pass variables, which you want optimize (that's not what `args` is for).

Comment: Also, when creating minimal example, try to use some dummy `function_opt`, because it's not where problem is. For example something like `def function_opt(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2, y): return b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + t1 + t2 + y` - i.e. something which can be used to "tune" the minimization part without the need to know what `function_opt` does.

Comment: Done, thank you so much, sorry for the really bad explanation I do but my english is not so good.

Comment: Ok, but it's not an example of the minimization problem. What I meant is something like (extremely simplified): `def function_opt:...; init_x = 0, 1, 2...; opt_result = minimize(...); print opt_result.x` which would be ''complete'' code which works and demonstrates your problem

Comment: Also, I still don't trully understand `y` - because what `minimize` does, is (very simplified) that it tries different values of some vector X (with initial value of x0) while all other parameters which the optimized function needs (and those MUST be constant) may be passed in `args`. For example I could have function `def myfn(a, b, scale): return (sin(a) + cos(b)) * scale` where I would want to optimize `a, b` parameters for given (constant) `scale` (for example 2). Then the call would be `minimize(myfn, [0.0, 0.0], args=(2.0,))`

Comment: Done, if it's not clear, don't worry I will keep trying and when I get it I will post it. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate that you take your time to help me.

Comment: I noticed you removed the `y` from the `objective` function - you should've kept it, because now it has different signature and the code looks different. So I added an answer for the original function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in passing `(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2)` as args - this should be
the optimization vector, so it should be passed only in a form of initial `x0`
(which you did). Since you removed `y` from `objective` function, there is no
need for `args` (which is for passing constant parameters of optimized
function).

This is what I think it should look like using `objective` function *after fixing (I made it complete with import and everything so you can run it without modification)*:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

y = 10.0

def objective(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2):
    return (y * b0 + b1) - ( y * b2 + b3) + t1 + t2

def objective_proxy(x):
    return objective(*x)

x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1])
result = minimize(objective_proxy, x0)
```

When you try it with the original function (which had `y` as last parameter),
you may pass the `y` in `args` now, because it's constant and the result would
look like this:

```
y_value = np.array([98.494500, 97.828500, 97.610000, 97.314000, 97.014500, 
92.959000, 96.696222])

def function_opt(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2, y):
    ...
    ...
    return ...

def function_opt_proxy(x, y):
    args = list(x) + [y]
    return function_opt(*args)


x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of b0, b1...
result = minimize(function_opt_proxy, x0, args=(y_value,)
```

Note that I changed `y` to `y_value` to avoid confusion between `function_opt`
parameter.

### fixed:

I added proxy function which takes care of expanding parameters from iterable to individual parameters.

Comment: Thanks. The output is:  
`def objective(b0, b1, b2, b3, t1, t2, y):  
    return  (((np.exp(b0 + (b1 + b2) * (1 - np.exp(-x/t1)) * t1/x - b2 * np.exp(-x/t1) + b3 * (1 - np.exp(-x/t2)) * t2 / x - b3 * np.exp(-x / t2)) -1) - y) ** 2).sum()

x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of b0, b1...
result = optimize.minimize(objective, x0, args=(y))  TypeError: objective() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'b2', 'b3', 't1', 't2', and 'y'`  x is a variable set before the function @Jan Spurny.  I think the problem is to connect the x0 values to the parameters of the function

Comment: Oh, I see.. my bad - fixing the answer now

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help